# Node JS request module - Cannot destructure property 'body'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, request

I have this code which returns the correct ID and name

```
request( url, function (error, response) {

    const data = JSON.parse(response.body)
    console.log(data.suggestions[1].entities[0].destinationId)
    console.log(data.suggestions[1].entities[0].name)

})
```

This works and returns me in the console a valid destination ID and name.

However I am trying to objectify my data with a callback function using the following:

```
request( {url: url, json:true}, (error, {body}) => {
    if (error) {
        callback('Unable to find hotel id!', undefined)
    } else {
        callback(undefined, {
                hotelId: body.suggestions[1].entities[0].destinationId,
                hotelName: body.suggestions[1].entities[0].name,
            })
    }  
})
```

I get the following error:

```
    request( {url: url, json:true}, (error, {body}) => {
                                         ^
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'body' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in the callback (the response) will be `undefined` in the case of an error and therefore cannot be destructured. One thing you could do is give the argument a default value of an empty object, then it can always be destructured even if the value passed in is `undefined`. i.e.

```js
request( {url: url, json:true}, (error, {body} = {}) => {
if (error) {
        callback('Unable to find hotel id!', undefined)
    } else {
        callback(undefined, {
                hotelId: body.suggestions[1].entities[0].destinationId,
                hotelName: body.suggestions[1].entities[0].name,
            })
    }  
})
```

However I would also suggest adding some defensive code to check that the `body` is not undefined or you will run into problems when you do `body.suggestions` in cases when you don't get a body.